# If $\varphi:V\to \mathbb R^n$ continuous and injective, why $\varphi|_{\bar B}: \bar B\to \varphi(\bar B)$ an homeomorphism ?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ open and $$\varphi:\Omega \to \mathbb R^m$$
continuous and injective. We suppose $m>n$. If $B\subset \bar B\subset \Omega $ is a ball, why $$\varphi|_{\bar B}: \bar B\to \varphi(\bar B)$$ is a homeomorphism ?

It's clear that $\varphi:\bar B\to \varphi(\bar B)$ is continuous and bijective. But why is it open ?

Comment: General fact: any continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is automatically a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the image of a compact under a continuous map is a compact.

A closed subset of a closed ball is compact (in $\mathbb R^n$). Hence the image of a closed subset is closed. Proving that the restriction of $\varphi$ to $\overline B$ is closed and therefore open as this restriction is a bijection.

Comment: I just don't get your last sentense : proving that the restriction of $\varphi$ to $\bar B$ is closed and therefore open.

Comment: For bijections, being close or open is equivalent.

Comment: Ok great thank you. And does it mean that $\varphi$ is local homeomorphism ?

Comment: Yes an open continuous bijection is an homeomorphism.

Comment: But here it's $\varphi|_{\bar B}$ that is an homeomorphism. This doesn't implies that for all $x$ there is an open $U\ni x$ and an open $V\ni f(x)$ s.t. $\varphi: U \to V$ that is an homeomorphism, does it ?

Comment: @UmbertoP.: no it's not the definition. [Here is the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_homeomorphism)

Comment: @UmbertoP.: This is an open application not an homeomorphism.

Comment: @UmbertoP. : Indeed, but it's not written that for all open $U$ the set $f(U)$ must be open.

Comment: @idm thanks for pointing out the error. I will revise my earlier comment.

Comment: @UmbertoP.: with pleasure :-)

Comment: @Peter: It will obviously be a local homeomorphism.